# Python pyplot histogram 0 bar is showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to make a histogram of some data that I have and for some reason histogram is keep showing the 0`th bar as well(Which is empty in my case)
here is my code

```
number_of_bins = 12
japanQuakes = pd.read_csv('JapanQuakes.csv', header=None).as_matrix()[1:,1].astype(np.int)
japanQuakes_histogram = plt.hist(japanQuakes, number_of_bins)

japanQuakes_histogram[0]
```

Note that japanQuakes contains numbers ranging from 1 to 12.

And here is the histogram that I get

[image]

So I want to find a way so that the bars fill the whole graph and the x axis starts from 1 instead of 0.

I tried to make the following to fix the problem

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
japanQuakes_histogram = plt.hist(japanQuakes, A)
```

But by doing this, it seems like last 2 bars gets stacked together and I end up with 11 bars instead of 12.

Also is there a way to make the x axis numbers appear under each bar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, setting the number of bins without any further specification will in most cases fail. Here, you make some implicit assumptions about the bins, namely you want to have 12 bins, equally spaced between 1 and 13. (But how should numpy know?!)

So it's always best to think about where to put the bins and to set them manually by supplying an array to `bins`. This array is interpreted as the limits of the bins, so for example setting `bins` to `[6,8,11]` produces two bins, with the first ranging from 6 to 8 (excluding 8.00) and the second from 8 to 11.

In your case you want 12 bins, so you need to supply the 13 numbers between 1 and 13 to `bins`, such that the value `1` belongs to the first bin, ranging from 1 to 2, and `12` belongs to the last bin ranging from 12 to 13.

This would already produce a nice histogram, however since you have only integer numbers, the bin width is kind of counterintuitive. So instead of having the bar centered in the middle of the bin, you might want to center it at the left point, which can be done by `align="left"`.

At the end you can set the limits of the plot just as you like.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# japanQuakes is the array [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
japanQuakes = np.arange(1,13) 

# if we want n bins, we need n+1 values in the array, since those are the limits
bins = np.arange(1,14)

japanQuakes_histogram, cbins, patches = plt.hist(japanQuakes, bins=bins, align="left")
# just to verify:
print japanQuakes_histogram
#[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
print cbins
#[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
# indeed we have one value between 1 and 2, one value between 2 and 3 and so on

# set xticks to match with the left bin limits
plt.gca().set_xticks(bins[:-1])

# if you want some space around
plt.gca().set_xlim([bins[0]-1,bins[-1]])
# or if you want it tight
#plt.gca().set_xlim([bins[0]-0.5,bins[-1]-0.5])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

How about to try the following?

```
plt.axis([1,12,0,3000])
A = np.arange(1,14)
japanQuakes_histogram = plt.hist(japanQuakes, A)
```

For the fine tuning, you can always change the parameter `bins`, but for the axises can be changed by `axis`.

Comment: The problem of setting the bins as `A = np.array(list(range(1,13)))` (mind there is a bracket missing) is that it will produce `11` bins. However questioner wants `12` bins.